# IncompatibleClassChangeError on WAS9 JDK8 after upgrading log4j jars from 2.11.1 to 2.13.2

Tags: java, java-8, log4j, websphere, log4j2

Receiving IncompatibleClassChangeError: class java/util/TreeMap has conflicting defaults for method computeIfAbsent on Websphere 9.x, IBM JDK8 after upgrading log4j api jars from 2.11.1 to 2.13.2 from PluginCache.getCategory() method Line#56

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! I can't help with this particular problem but I can direct you to a resource on solving IncompatibleClassChangeErrors in Java: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-how-to-resolve-incompatible-class-change-error/

Comment: This is a little baffling. PluginCache doesn't extend any other class. The TreeMap is a private member of the class. I don't understand what the message "TreeMap has conflicting defaults for method computeIfAbsent" means.  I would suggest opening a support ticket with IBM.

Comment: Did you try clearing the classcache for the updated server as outlined here https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-clear-websphere-class-caches?